# Selenium Webdriver to handle java script text box

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to specify zip code to a input field to fetch the restaurant locations. I am able to specify the zip code and unable to hit the enter key. As its doesn't has enter button it needs to be handled via javascript.  Need help in resolving issue:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    String baseURL = "http://www.thecheesecakefactory.com/";
    driver.get(baseURL);
    // Go to Menu
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='topNav']/li[1]/a")).click();
    // Click on Pizza
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='firstScroller']/li[7]/a")).click();
    // Select Hawallian Pizza
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='secondScroller']/li[6]/a")).click();
    //String pageTitle = "Hawaiian Pizza";
    String aTitle = driver.getTitle();
    if (aTitle.equalsIgnoreCase("Hawaiian Pizza")){
        System.out.println("Yes its Hawaiian Pizza");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }
    //Click to order and get locations
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='receiptMenu']/div[1]/div[3]/div/a/b")).click();
    WebElement element;
    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='location_box']/div[2]/input"));
    element.sendKeys("84604", Keys.ENTER);
}
```

Comment: What ever you have just given above make no sense. You have to explain what is the issue you are facing.

Comment: out of curiosity why are you using xpath for finding everything?  Your test code will be clearer if you use attributes like id and class if at all possible first.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement element;
element = driver.findElement("//*[@id='location_box']/div[2]/input");
element.sendKeys("84604", Keys.ENTER);
```

There is an typo error in the above code.

```
WebElement element;
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='location_box']/div[2]/input"));
element.sendKeys("84604", Keys.ENTER);
```

I checked the code it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, inspite of the above code change it did not work. Specified zip code is entered in the input box but Keys.ENTER is not effective.

Comment: Well, its not working for me :( when I manually hit enter, result will be displayed. Any clue where I am going wrong?

Comment: I don't know what's going wrong. Try to use [`Actions`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#sendKeys%28org.openqa.selenium.WebElement,%20java.lang.CharSequence...%29) class Or [`java.awt.Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class.